# Change Skybox Material Programmatically (c#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, skybox

I want to change the default skybox material so I made this lines... After that I only see blue... What's my mistake?

the material is on the Assets folder by the away

```
Material levelMat = Resources.Load(Application.dataPath + "/testeVR.mat", typeof(Material)) as Material;
RenderSettings.skybox = levelMat;
```

Comment: Does it has specular/texture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the material is on the Assets folder by the away

You can't place the material in the Asset folder if you are loading it with  `Resources.Load`.

> After that I only see blue

The `levelMat` variable is `null`. You get blue when the material you are applying to the Skybox is null and you can prove this by adding `Debug.Log(levelMat);` after it.

> Material levelMat = Resources.Load(Application.dataPath +
>   "/testeVR.mat", typeof(Material)) as Material;

You can't do this either. The `Application.dataPath` should not be used in the path parameter of the `Resources.Load` function.

Few things to understand from your code:

**1**.`Resources.Load` requires a special folder called *Resources*. Create a folder called *Resources* in the Assets directory then place the *testeVR.mat* inside it.

**2**.You do **not** put the file extension in the path parameter of the `Resources.Load` function. So, *testeVR.mat* should actually be *testeVR* without "*.mat*".

Simply create a folder called *Resources* in the *Assets* Folder then place the *testeVR* material inside this place. It should look like this: *Assets/Resources/testeVR.mat*. The code below should be used to load it.

```
Material levelMat = Resources.Load("testeVR", typeof(Material)) as Material;
```

Now, lets say that you have another folder called "*Mats*" which is in the *Resources* folder. You would use something like below:

```
Material levelMat = Resources.Load("Mats/testeVR", typeof(Material)) as Material;
```

Answer (score 1):

just create public variable of material and place the material you want to be load during runtime or if you want to load it via some function use this

```
RenderSetting.sky = skyboxMat;
```

skyboxMat stored the material which drag it in unity and then it becomes apart of your skybox

```
public Material skyboxMat;
voidstart(){ RenderSetting.skybox = skyboxMat;}
```

Comment: This works in editor and iOS. But in Android, it fails? Still get blue in Android.